# How to reduce the size of AWS Lambda code written in JAVA in Eclipse

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-lambda

I am an android developer and exploring Amazon AWS for my future appliaction as a backend option. I had explored various AWS services such as dynamoDB, S3, SES and cool lambda feature with JAVA. During my learing I found/prepared a code for creating thumbnail images for every image uploaded to S3 bucket. I successfully written the Lambda code in java in eclipse IDE and able to upload and use it using AWS console for the purpose it was intended.

My Concern is that when I uploaded the JAVA Lambda code to AWS it appears 49 MB in SIZE. When I seek for the reason I found that there are plenty of jars were used in project under AWS sdk for java. Is this normal or I can reduce the size of uploaded code anyhow. Please guide me How can I reduce the size efficiently. I also seen the node.js Lambda code for same and its in KBs only. Might bbe I am doing some wrong things.

Please Help...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple answer - you're doing it right and package size can't be reduced to a size comparable to a node.js application.

For node.js lambda, amazon has AWS SDK libraries in place so you have to upload only your own code and third party libraries. But for java lambda, the AWS SDK must be packaged with the application.

But you can reduce package size by carefully selecting which libraries to include and excluding unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

My first Java Lambda functions were also quite large. My HelloWorld Java function was 10+ MB! When you're following the Java function deployment tutorial on the AWS website, you'll get the impression that it's necessary to package the AWS-sdk. It's not.

I've tested this and came to the conclusion that itsn't necessary to package the AWS-sdk to run a Lambda function. If you're using Maven you can set the AWS-sdk to provided, by:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.72</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

When you package you function into a JAR, this will result in a function of a few KB's.

[Screenshot from AWS Lambda console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNi87.png)

Comment: Hi @Martijn, Thanks for your suggestion. However I am not familiar with Maven project, can you help me in another way i.e., a usual project created using eclipse new projet wizard. Hope I am clear with what I am asking for.

Comment: @GrvJn How are you creating a JAR file? I use Maven or SBT to manage the dependencies for the project i'm running. [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-and-eclipse.html) This will show you how to create a deployment package using Maven and Eclipse. inside the <Dependencies></Dependencies> XML tag, put the above <dependency> code to exclude the SDK from the JAR build. Note that you'll need this SDK if your function is doing AWS Specific things, like interacting with DynamoDB or S3.

Comment: I've setup a demo github repo for you to try out, you can fetch it here: https://github.com/martijnvdgrift/StackOverFlowTest

Comment: I am using the way given at [How to Create, Upload and Invoke an AWS Lambda Function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/ug//lambda-tutorial.html)

Comment: @MartijnVandeGrift I don't think this is true (I wish it were). I think it only worked for you because you didn't actually use the AWS SDK. If you did, you would have got a NoClassDefFoundError at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

Having a JAR size of 49 MB seems a bit large to me depending on what libraries you are including. If you are including the full AWS SDK (all services) this can add quite a bit of size to your JARs. I'm assuming your own code and other libraries are nominal in size. If you are using Maven then you can include only the libraries for the services you need (ex: S3) and save by not including the ones you do not.

A good resource is the [Managing Dependencies with AWS SDK for Java - Bill of Materials module (BOM)](https://java.awsblog.com/post/TxQPN0AEKT3F48/Managing-Dependencies-with-AWS-SDK-for-Java-Bill-of-Materials-module-BOM) blog post. While it is technically about a slightly different topic, it demonstrates the best practice around package management for the AWS SDK in Java. By including the package `aws-java-sdk-s3` instead of `aws-java-sdk` as an example you will see a substantial reduction in the package size, AWS has a lot of services and their full SDK is quite large.

What I see with many of my Java based Lambda functions is a deployment size of 10 MB to 13 MB depending on what other 3rd party libraries I need to include. You definitely cannot get the deployment size anywhere near what node.js is at just based on the nature of how the Java deployment works, but there should be room to improve from where you are at.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I am not familiar with Maven project and only has a knowledge with simple eclipse wizard projects. Can you please guide me in that way to remove dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider looking at [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) an open source jar shrinker / optimizer. I've found it has helped me reduce lambda functions from 15Mb to 3Mb. I can probably get it lower than that with more careful use of the proguard options, but I'm happy enough with that saving for now.

My SBT based settings for a Scala lambda function are as follows - but you should, I think,  get similar reductions for a Java lambda function.

```
ProguardKeys.options in Proguard ++= Seq(
"-dontoptimize",
"-dontobfuscate",
"-dontnote",
"-dontwarn",
"-keep,includedescriptorclasses class mypackage.** { *; }",
)
```

Comment: HI Roger!, I am new to 'proguard' Could you guide me how can I add/use proguard to my Java Lambda code in Eclipse fro beginning. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aws-lightweight-client-java](https://github.com/davidmoten/aws-lightweight-client-java) which is a standalone jar (no dependencies) and **is less than 60K**. The reduced number of classes can also reduce Lambda cold start times a lot (see the project for details). The catch is you have to learn a bit more about the AWS API through its documentation instead of relying on auto-complete in an IDE with the fat generated code in the AWS SDK jars. As a quick example this is how you would code the reading of an object from an s3 bucket inside a Lambda handler:

```
Client s3 = Client.s3().defaultClient().build();
String bytes = s3.path("myBucket", "myObject.txt").responseAsBytes();
```

This example was coded with *com.github.davidmoten:aws-lightweight-client-java:0.1.3* (but you should check the project for the most recent release).